# Issue with the update frequency of the LeafSystem in Drake

Tags: drake

I built a differential inverse kinematics system, and connected it to the `ManipulationStation`. The default time step, 0.002 was chosen. In my view, the callback function in the differential inverse kinematics system is called every 0.002 second. However, when printing the `Context` of the system inside the callback function, the following results showed.

```
::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 5e-05

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.0001

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.0001

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.00035

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.0006

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.0006

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.0013

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.002

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.002

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.003

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.004

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.004

::diagram::__main__.DifferentialIKSystem@0000000004076300 Context
------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 0.005
```

Why does the simulation time not increase by 0.002?

Comment: Wild guess: you are running in continuous mode where a variable-step integrator is choosing the step size?

Comment: I passed the argument, `time_step` to the `ManipulationStation`. Hence, I think I am using a discrete plant. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

The manipulation station example diagram has many systems in it.  The answer will depend on where specifically your callback function is located, and what other systems you have in your diagram.

The `ManipulationStation` has a `MultibodyPlant` inside it; if you set the `time_step` of that system it will set the `time_step` of the plant (putting it into discrete mode).  But the `DifferentialIkSystem` in the `examples/manipulation_station` folder is also a dynamical system, it has it’s own `time_step`, which need not be the same as the plant.  And you might have other systems in the diagram that cause the simulator to make integration steps that are different than the plant `time_step`.

In particular, the output of the `DifferentialIkSystem` is being fed to the `iiwa_position` input, which actually feeds directly through to the `iiwa_position` output port.  So any system requesting that output from the `ManipulationStation` will be asking for the `DifferentialIkSystem` to compute it’s output port value.  So if your callback is in the output method, you would expect that to trigger at any time a downstream system is requesting the value of that output port.

Comment: Come to think of it, the `InverseDynamicsController` inside `ManipulationStation` has a (continuous time) integrator in it.  That will cause your DiffIK to be evaluated.  My guess is that the samples are coming from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code used for my test above is from the textbook of Robotic Manipulation. The `PseudoInverseController` is connected to an `Integrator` (continuous time) in that notebook. I think it is the `Integrator` that requests the value of the output port of the `PseudoInverseController`.